# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting collection type [java.lang.Object] after upgrading Hibernate-core to 5.6

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, bag, hibernate-xml-mapping

**after upgrading hibernate from 5.0.2 to 5.6.15 and spring from 5.3.22 to 5.3.31
got this error:**

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [multiElementEditorDefinitionsList, structure]
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [multiElementEditorDefinitionsList, structure]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadQueryDetails.generate(AbstractLoadQueryDetails.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails.<init>(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:85)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.BatchingLoadQueryDetailsFactory.makeEntityLoadQueryDetails(BatchingLoadQueryDetailsFactory.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.<init>(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.<init>(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:112)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

**solved By changing the fetch to select instead of join at this part on one of the hbm.xml files:**

```
<bag name="multiElementEditorDefinitionsList" cascade="persist,merge,save-update,delete-orphan" lazy="false" fetch="select" inverse="true">
    <key column="TEMPLATE_ID" on-delete="cascade"/>
    <one-to-many class="MultiElementEditorDefinitions"/>
</bag>
```

**then I got this Error:**

```
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting collection type [java.lang.Object]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.determineCollectionType(AttributeFactory.java:982)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.<init>(AttributeFactory.java:827)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.<init>(AttributeFactory.java:808)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.determineAttributeMetadata(AttributeFactory.java:587)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.buildAttribute(AttributeFactory.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.determineSimpleType(AttributeFactory.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.buildAttribute(AttributeFactory.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext.wrapUp(MetadataContext.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:728)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:616)
```

**at this subclass, especially the m_basedOnItems component:**

```xml
<subclass name="ReferenceBusinessField" discriminator-value="3">
   <join table="BIS_REFERENCE_FIELD">
       <key column="ID" on-delete="cascade"/>
       <component name="m_defaultValue" class="{class1}" access="field">
           <component name="value" class="{class2}">
               <property name="externalId" type="string" column="DEFAULT_VALUE" length="255"/>
           </component>
           <property name="overridden" column="DEFAULT_VALUE_OVERRIDDEN" type="boolean"/>
       </component>
       <component name="m_basedOnItems" class="{class1}" access="field">
           <bag name="value" table="BIS_REF_FIELD_SUBTYPE" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="all">
               <key column="FIELD_ID"/>
               <element column="BASED_ON_ITEM_ID" type="{class3}"/>
           </bag>
       </component>
   </join>
   <subclass name="ReferenceBusinessEntityField" discriminator-value="4"/>
</subclass>
```

**what I tried:**
I added all compile dependencies and tried to change the bag to set/list/map still getting same error
I also tried to change `<element>` to `one-to-many` ...
tried to use `<composite-element>` inside the bag
also tried adding this component but led to another error related to db:
`<property name="overridden" column="BASED_ON_ITEM_OVERRIDDEN" type="boolean"/>`

but nothing helped!

**please Advice!**

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You are eagerly loading multiple references and that is now prohibited by Hibernate due to several issues with that. Make the collections lazy loading instead of eager.

Comment: you mean changing lazy to lazy="true" in all the collections like bag/set/list/map ..?

Comment: Yes. If you have multiple non-lazy collections you will get a cartesian product (all the rows from table x multipled by the rows from table y multiplied by the rows of table z, hence way too much data and hibernate needs to deal with this).

Comment: got it, but I already tried this and getting same Expecting collection type [java.lang.Object] ERROR

Comment: Was focussing on the initial error. You are probably missing a type somewhere or to specify the generic type of a collection.

Comment: but it was working proper before the hibernate and spring upgrade

Comment: And you expect that nothing changes in versions? Hibernate is becoming more and more strict in configuration and queries (version 6 is even more strict).